# Color of patches based on range of numeric values from a Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization

I'm looking for some assistance to the following issue I am having:

- I have a Pandas DataFrame which contains x and y coordinates of a FEM mesh from which I can draw a polygon collection
- I want to then color each patch according to a calculated value of its utilization (which ranges from 0 to 1). 0 should be green with a transition to red for 1.
- seaborn.scatterplot has this capability with the parameter "hue", is there a way to do this with matplotlib patches?

Current code:

```
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        patches = []

        df = pd.DataFrame(table_data)
        df.columns = df.iloc[0]
        df = df.drop(df.index[0])

        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            polygon = Polygon([(row["x_1"], row["y_1"]),
                               (row["x_2"], row["y_2"]),
                               (row["x_3"], row["y_3"])])
            patches.append(polygon)
        
        p = PatchCollection(patches, cmap = cm.coolwarm, alpha=0.4)
        ax.add_collection(p)    
        ax.autoscale(enable = True, axis = "both", tight = True)
        plt.show()
```

The plot looks as follows:

[Current plot with one color for all patches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0x7y.png)

The Pandas DataFrame looks something like this:

```
0      #    x_1    y_1    x_2    y_2    x_3  ... Syy [MPa] Sxy [MPa] fEd,max [kN/m] fEd,min [kN/m]  µwarp  µweft
1      1    6.0    0.0  5.644  0.356  5.831  ...       2.0       0.0            2.0          1.999  0.082  0.092     
2      2  5.831  0.432  5.644  0.356  5.388  ...       2.0      -0.0            2.0          1.999  0.082  0.092     
3      3   3.32   2.68    3.0    3.0  3.363  ...       2.0      -0.0            2.0            2.0  0.082  0.092     
4      4  0.703  5.297  0.356  5.644  0.861  ...       2.0       0.0            2.0            2.0  0.082  0.092     
5      5  4.622  1.378  4.292  1.708  4.598  ...       2.0       0.0            2.0            2.0  0.082  0.092     
..   ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...  ...       ...       ...            ...            ...    ...    ...     
368  368  1.865  2.844  2.183  2.569  2.095  ...       2.0      -0.0            2.0            2.0  0.082  0.092     
369  369  1.865  2.844  2.095  3.069  1.501  ...       2.0       0.0            2.0            2.0  0.082  0.092     
370  370  4.536  1.088  4.461  0.759   5.04  ...       2.0      -0.0            2.0          1.999  0.082  0.092     
371  371  1.572  3.631  1.142   4.03  1.149  ...       2.0       0.0            2.0            2.0  0.082  0.092     
372  372  1.545  2.682  1.485  2.029  2.107  ...     1.999       0.0          1.999          1.999  0.082  0.092
```

The color scale should be based off of `df["µwarp"]`. It would be cool to do something like this: [link](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-surface3d-py)

I have tried adding the series `df["µwarp"]` to the parameter "color" for `PatchCollection()` but this was not valid.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!